# How do I check to see if a string contains specific characters, and if it does replace just that bit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to replace all strings that contain the characters `c#` which can include `c#-4.0`, `c#-3.0`, `ms-c#`, etc.

How do I check to see if `c#` exists within a string, and if it does, just replace the `c#` portion of that string?

i.e. for `c#-4.0` the modified string would be `c%23-4.0`. It would be preferable if a native method of the Ruby core library is used (like one of `String`'s methods).

I tried `tagname.replace('c%23')` but that replaces the entire string, and not just the substring that matches the pattern.

Thoughts?

Comment: `gsub` ? http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub (or just `sub` if you want to replace only once in the string)

Comment: I looked at that....but iono why I read that it just does regexps, and not strings. Maybe because the examples don't have any strings, I just assumed. That's good. If you add it as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: `"c#-4.0".gsub("c#", "c%23")` will work just the same. The regular expression support is there for when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [String gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) method:

```
"c#-4.0".gsub!(/c#/, "c%23")
```

Comment: Caution: `gsub!` returns `nil` when the search string is not found. Your original post did not say "And if the string `c#` is not found, I want to return `nil`."

`"c++-4.0".gsub!(/c#/, "c%23") => nil`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`gsub`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) method of String. (Use [`sub`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/sub) if you want to replace only once in the string).

```
"hello".gsub(/[aeiou]/, '*')                  #=> "h*ll*"
"hello".gsub(/([aeiou])/, '<\1>')             #=> "h<e>ll<o>"
"hello".gsub(/./) {|s| s.ord.to_s + ' '}      #=> "104 101 108 108 111 "
"hello".gsub(/(?<foo>[aeiou])/, '{\k<foo>}')  #=> "h{e}ll{o}"
'hello'.gsub(/[eo]/, 'e' => 3, 'o' => '*')    #=> "h3ll*"

# in your case :
"some string c#".gsub!('c#', 'c%23')           #=> "some string c%23"
```

Comment: Added the `!` to return a modified string.

Comment: `gsub!` does not return the (in-place) modified string unless a modification has been made. `gsub` always returns a copy of the string and leaves the source string as-is.

Comment: Right...that's what I want. If the substring `c#` exists in the string, then modify that string. I don't want it to return a copy of that string if it finds `c#`.